# How can I send one-way messages between Python scripts of different versions on a local machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipc

I have a first sender script in Python 3.10 which needs to send some data

```
def post_updates(*args):
   sender.send_message("optional_key", args)
```

Then a second receiver script in Python 3.7 which needs to receive this data

```
while True:
   args = receiver.get_message("optional_key", blocking=True)
   print("args received:", args)
```

Constraints:

- Each script should not depend on the presence of the other to run.
- The sender should try to send regardless if the receiver is running.
- The receiver should try to receive regardless if the sender is running.
- The message can consist of basic python objects (dict, list) and should be serialized automatically.
- I need to send over 100 messages per second (minimizing latency if possible).
- Local PC only (Windows) and no need for security.

Are there 1-liner solutions to this simple problem?  Everything I look up seems overly complicated or requires a TCP server to be started beforehand.  I don't mind installing popular modules.

**EDIT:**

I expected there would be modules that could conveniently allow the exchange of basic Python objects without having to implement code and deal with quirks. I have not found any, so I posted a working solution below, inspired from suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like the messages are treated as independent of each other?

Comment: You are asking folks to vote on a beauty contest between 0mq, kafka, rabbitMQ, linda, etc. Pick one or two libraries and ask a question focused on those. _Every_ problem becomes a one-liner once you've coded up a function to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an actual solution, this is the simplest I found to meet all requirements.

```py
import json
import time
import zmq
import os

class ZmqSender():
    def __init__(self, addr="tcp://127.0.0.1:12345"):
        self.ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.sock = self.ctx.socket(zmq.PUB) # TCP Publisher (UDP/RADIO/DISH unavailable)
        self.sock.connect(addr) # Here many publishers can connect, one subscriber will bind
        self.pid = os.getpid()  # Cached for performance

    def send_message(self, *args):
        msg = dict(_pid=self.pid, _qpc=time.perf_counter(), args=args)
        self.sock.send(json.dumps(msg).encode())

class ZmqReceiver():
    def __init__(self, addr="tcp://127.0.0.1:12345"):
        self.ctx = zmq.Context()
        self.sock = self.ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)  # Subscriber
        self.sock.bind(addr)    # Here one subscriber (the stable end) binds the port
        self.sock.subscribe('') # Subscribe to any publishing

    def get_pending_messages(self):
        """Returns a list of all messages in input buffer without blocking."""
        msgs = []
        try:
            while True:  # repeat until no further messages
                msgs.append(json.loads(self.sock.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK))) # JSON decode
        except zmq.Again as e:
            pass    # No further message awaiting
        return msgs
```

Then for the sender:

```py
zs = ZmqSender()
zs.send_message("Hello", 12345, dict(key=999))
```

And the receiver:

```py
zr = ZmqReceiver()
while True:
    for msg in zr.get_pending_messages():
        print(msg)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

If someone has a simpler solution, then please share ;-)

Answer (score 0):

UDP and JSON look perfect for what you're asking for, as long as

- you don't need there to be more than one receiver
- you don't need very large messages
- you just need to send combinations of dicts, lists, strings, and numbers, not Python objects of arbitrary classes
- you're not being overly literal about finding a "1-liner": it's a very small amount of code to write, and you're free to define your own helper functions.

Python's standard library has all you need for this. Encoding and decoding from JSON is as simple as `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`. For sending and receiving, I suggest following [the example on the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication). You need to create the socket first with

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

regardless of if you're making the sender or the receiver. The receiver will then need to bind to the local port to listen to it:

```
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
```

And then the sender sends with `sock.sendto()` and the receiver receives with `sock.recvfrom()`.

Answer (score -1):

The good old pipe might do the job, but you need to assess how big the buffer size needs to be (given the async nature of your sender/receiver), and change the default pipe buffer size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).